# Can't get computer to connect to GSM modem

Tags: putty, gsm, at-command, modem

I'm a student working on a project that involves interacting with a GSM modem via AT commands.  I've been having trouble connecting my computer to the modem.

What I know: The modem is on, the drivers are installed, a SIM card is in one of the modem's ports, and I see the COM ports in the device manager.

However, when I try to use PuTTY to enter with serial, it launches, but it never works.  On one of the ports, it lets me type, but it never responds when I use the command "AT".  On all the others, it simply won't let me type anything.

I have been stuck on this for a while and any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the model of the modem? How are you connecting its serial port to your computer – a USB-to-serial interface – which chipset does it use? Or does the modem connect to the computer via USB and present a virtual serial port? What baud rate are you using in PuTTY when you open the port? Have you confirmed with your modem's manual that PuTTY is sending the expected line endings? Some modems will accept CR, LF, or any combination of the two; others are much more strict.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl It is not necessarily off topic, as stated by the community after [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403258/11336762). Of course the condition is to have issues with AT commands synthax and functionality. If the issue is in the correct connection of the device, the suitable place is HW SO.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Aggred. To me this looks pretty much like a connection problem.

Comment: In this case we are  probably in the middle: not a "wiring issue" but a port configuration problem. Is it a physical RS232 or a USB? Have you correctly set the serial parameters (i.e. 8N1, baudrate 115200)?

Comment: _"On one of the ports, it lets me type, but it never responds when I use the command "AT"."_ -- do you get the letters echoed back from the modem, so it's not just local echo? Probably so, if the other ports don't echo the letters back. The modem might require carriage return (CR) characters to the end the command, and the terminal might be sending linefeeds (LF) instead. Check if fiddling with the related settings helps (there's some under "Terminal" in Putty), and try if Ctrl-J works to end the command, it should be the CR character.